# A very strange case of DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, calculated-columns, entity-framework-migrations

Today I've found and an exception in my code.

### DbUpdateConcurrencyException

It was very confusing because there were no changes in business logic and there was no updating of entities. After some hours of trying to understand I decided to turn on SQL Server profiler.

And here is an example of issue that I found.
Lets look at Foo entity definition:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    public Foo(int someId, DateTime createdAt, int x, int y)
    {
        SomeId = someId;
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int SomeId { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; private set; }

    public int X { get; private set; }

    public int Y { get; private set; }
}
```

If you try to add an instance of Foo and save db context it will work.

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var foo = new Foo(1, now, 2, 2);
    myDbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);
    myDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Below is code that is executed when you save changes.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Foo]([SomeId], [CreatedAt], [X], [Y])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
',N'@0 int,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 int',@0=1,@1='2015-10-15 12:45:15.2580302',@2=2,@3=2
```

Now lets add a computed column.

```
    public int Sum { get; private set; }
```

Bellow is code for creation column in migration.

```
Sql("alter table dbo.Foo add Sum as (X + Y)");
```

Update the database. Now the code throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException. And here is why. If we look in SQL Server profiler, we'll see the code above:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Foo]([SomeId], [CreatedAt], [X], [Y])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
SELECT [Sum]
FROM [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [SomeId] = @0 AND [CreatedAt] = @1',N'@0 int,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 int',@0=1,@1='2015-10-15 12:55:29.4479727',@2=2,@3=2
```

Now the query returns [Sum] column because it is computed. Insertion works well. But result set is empty. I think it causes DbUpdateConcurrencyException. The problem is in type of @1 variable. It is datetime2(7), but if you look in type of CreatedAt column you'll see that it is datetime. If you execute the script above, you’ll find a new row with '2015-10-15 12:55:29.447' in CreatedAt column (cast works fine). But query tries to find [Sum] of the row where CreatedAt equals to '2015-10-15 12:55:29.4479727'. Of cause the result set is empty.

---

So, you can fix the problem in two ways:

1. Change the precision of column value (for example without milliseconds).
2. Set manually the type of CreatedAt column in migration (datetime2(7)).

In my case I select first because I don't want to change database schema.

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=36F9B3A382C99DC4!127402&authkey=!AEd6UPxzM0tcktw&ithint=file%2Czip) is the project to reproduce the problem.

PS: Sorry for my English:)

Comment: I have edited your original question to include the details you provided as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And here is an example of issue that I found.
Lets look at Foo entity definition:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    public Foo(int someId, DateTime createdAt, int x, int y)
    {
        SomeId = someId;
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int SomeId { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; private set; }

    public int X { get; private set; }

    public int Y { get; private set; }
}
```

If you try to add an instance of Foo and save db context it will work.

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var foo = new Foo(1, now, 2, 2);
    myDbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);
    myDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Below is code that is executed when you save changes.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Foo]([SomeId], [CreatedAt], [X], [Y])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
',N'@0 int,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 int',@0=1,@1='2015-10-15 12:45:15.2580302',@2=2,@3=2
```

Now lets add a computed column.

```
    public int Sum { get; private set; }
```

Bellow is code for creation column in migration.

```
Sql("alter table dbo.Foo add Sum as (X + Y)");
```

Update the database. Now the code throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException. And here is why. If we look in SQL Server profiler, we'll see the code above:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Foo]([SomeId], [CreatedAt], [X], [Y])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
SELECT [Sum]
FROM [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [SomeId] = @0 AND [CreatedAt] = @1',N'@0 int,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 int',@0=1,@1='2015-10-15 12:55:29.4479727',@2=2,@3=2
```

Now the query returns [Sum] column because it is computed. Insertion works well. But result set is empty. I think it causes DbUpdateConcurrencyException. The problem is in type of @1 variable. It is datetime2(7), but if you look in type of CreatedAt column you'll see that it is datetime. If you execute the script above, you’ll find a new row with '2015-10-15 12:55:29.447' in CreatedAt column (cast works fine). But query tries to find [Sum] of the row where CreatedAt equals to '2015-10-15 12:55:29.4479727'. Of cause the result set is empty.

---

So, you can fix the problem in two ways:

1. Change the precision of column value (for example without milliseconds).
2. Set manually the type of CreatedAt column in migration (datetime2(7)).

In my case I select first because I don't want to change database schema.

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=36F9B3A382C99DC4!127402&authkey=!AEd6UPxzM0tcktw&ithint=file%2Czip) is the project to reproduce the problem.

PS: Sorry for my English:)

Comment: what is your version of SQL server ?

Comment: the Problem might as well be in the modelBuilder/DB. however, for using of DateTime2 you'll have to state so in fluent API modelbuilder/ Data Annotations

Answer (score 1):

facing quite a similar case I use the following extension method

```
public static DateTime RoundedToSeconds(this DateTime dt) {
    return new DateTime(dt.Ticks - (dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond), dt.Kind);
}
```

then your code should be

```
public Foo(int someId, DateTime createdAt, int x, int y)
{
    SomeId = someId;
    CreatedAt = createdAt.RoundedToSeconds();
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

IMHO you may use a rounding to ms.

Answer (score 1):

This issue doesn't repro with current builds of Entity Framework Core. The parameter type for the `CreatedAt` becomes of type `DateTime2`.

I think you missed mentioning that the key of the entity contains both `SomeId` and `CreatedAt`.